# How does bipush work in JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-bytecode

I understand iload takes in integers -1 to 5, but how can you extend to higher numbers using a bipush instruction? How is the specific integer being stored with the bytecode?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, whether you're asking about pushing the values of local variables onto the stack when you have more than 4 local variables to choose from (`iload`), or pushing literals with `bipush`.

Comment: I'm really asking about both. Is iload_1 loading the integer one?

Comment: `iload_1` pushes the `int` in local variable #1 (the second one, since it's zero-based) onto the stack.

Comment: My mistake, I was getting the instructions mixed. When you are using istore, and you are storing more than 4 variables, how does it handle the size? I figured the variable field is a fixed array.

Comment: The size of what?

Comment: The fixed size of the variable field.

Comment: What is a "variable field"?

Comment: Variable field is how Hotspot VM stores local variables within each frame.

Answer (score 12):

There's several different instructions that can be used to push an integer constant.

The smallest is the iconst_* instructions. These are only a single byte, because the value is encoded in the opcode itself. iconst_1, iconst_2, etc. are different opcodes. `iconst_5` for example would be encoded as the byte `08`.

Note: `iload` is a completely unrelated instruction used for loading the value of a local variable. You must have been thinking of iconst_*.

Next is `bipush`, which can push a constant between -128 and 127. This instruction is two bytes long - the first byte is the opcode, and the second byte is a signed 8 bit integer. You can even use it to push constants in the range -1 to 5, although doing so would take up more space in the classfile than necessary. For example, `bipush 5` would be encoded as `10 05`. (0x10 is the opcode for bipush)

Next is `sipush`, which is the same except that it stores a 16 bit constant instead of an 8 bit constant, and hence the instruction is three bytes long. The opcode for sipush is 0x11, so `sipush 5` would be encoded as the three byte sequence `11 00 05`.

You might wonder how integer constants which don't fit in 16 bits are stored. In this case, the compiler creates entries in a separate section of the classfile called the constant pool, and then uses the `ldc` or `ldc_w` instruction to refer to the constant pool entry.

Comment: So how is a bytecode implemented in the interpreter if it's holding an instruction and a value? I thought each bytecode is an int8_t.

Comment: @Tim Each *opcode* is one byte. Depending on their definitions, operations can be followed by operands.

Comment: Since it's one byte, how are there two values, integer and bipush instruction?

Comment: What general component in a JVM interpreter is the integer argument made?

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [section 2.11 of the JVMS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11), which deals with instruction representation. In particular, it uses the obvious order: the opcode, immediately followed by operands in order, big-endian (as all Java representations). In the case of `bipush`, this would be [the byte 0x10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se10/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.bipush) followed by the literal value.